# PHP Error when returning value into new array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, syntax

I want to build a new array using values returned from a static method from another class, like so:

```
class Foo {
    public static $vars = array(
        'foo' => Config::method('returns a string'), /* line where error occurs */
        'bar' => Config::anothermethod('another string')
    );
}
```

Now PHP throws this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in file.php on line 22`

The method simply returns a string, which I double checked. I even tried stringifying it with `(string) Config::method('foo')` , no success. Is this not possible?

Comment: May I ask what the reason for the downvote was?

Comment: Questions should generally include all code needed to reproduce the issue at hand. There is no declaration for Queue in your question. That said, I'm not the person that downvoted you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaration of class variables must be a constant expression.  Method calls are not constant expressions.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

Comment: That makes things clearer, thank you. I am still trying to find my way into OOP.